# use of $timeout with 0 milliseconds

Tags: html, angularjs

```
HttpMethod.CallHttpPOSTMethod('POST',null, path).success(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    $scope.htmlString = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data[0]);
    $timeout(function () {
        var temp = document.getElementById('form');
        if (temp != null) {
            temp.submit();
        }
    }, 0);
});
```

I will get html string in RESPONSE of my API call. And then I will add the html to my view page.

If I write the code outside  $timeout service it wont work as it will work when written inside  `$timeout service`.

1. What is the difference between two ways?
2. How is $timeout useful here?

Answer (score 0):

When you make any changes to the controller, it does not start asynchronously for two-way binding. If the asynchronous code is wrapped in special ones: `$timeout, $scope.$apply, etc. binding will happen. For the current code example, I would have tried replace you code to:

```
HttpMethod.CallHttpPOSTMethod('POST',null, path).success(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
  $scope.htmlString = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data[0]);
  var temp = document.getElementById('form');
  if (temp != null) {
    temp.submit();
  }
  $scope.$apply();                
});
```

Comment: Trying this code throws the below error

Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

Comment: I can be wrong, but it looks like you have somewhere in the code appearing an infinite cycle of 2-sided binding. Therefore, you also took $ digest

Comment: It means if I remove $timeout with 0 milliseconds, the code is creating infinite loop of 2 way binding?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to give you an answer in very simple language, hope it may help to understand your issue.

Generally, When HTTP request fires to execute it will send to the server and get the data from the server this is the general scenario we have in our mind. There may be a situation occur that sometime due to network latency it may possible to receive response delay.

AngluarJs application has its own lifecycle.
Root scope is created during application bootstrap by the $injector. In template linking, directive binding creates new child scope.
While template linking there is watch registered to particular scope to identify particular changes.

In your case, when template linking and binding directive, there is a new watcher registered. Due to network latency or other reason your $http request sends delay response to your $http request and meanwhile those time scope variable has been changed. due to that, it will not give the updated response.

When you send $http request to a server it is asynchronous operation. When you use $timeout ultimately your scope binding wait to  numbers of seconds in $timeout function you defined. After n number of seconds, your scope variable watch has been executed and it will update the value if you get the response in time.

Comment: It means $watch service is called internally?

Comment: yes, When you create a data binding from somewhere in your view to a variable on the $scope object, AngularJS creates a "watch" internally.

Comment: Please review link: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html. It will help to you.

Comment: Thank you Dipak. I will refer the link first.